# Apple Mapkit Navigation: Does Mapkit gives callback on reaching destination point?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, navigation, mapkit

I am using Apple Mapkit navigation in one of my application, it is working fine when I give start location and destination location. But it does not throw me any callback when it reaches to destination point into my ViewController. Is there any callback to handle this or any other way around to tackle this. Actually on desctination reached I want to switch to next ViewController.

Here is my code:

```
class AppleMap {
    
    var source: CLLocationCoordinate2D? = nil
    var destination: CLLocationCoordinate2D? = nil

    init(source: CLLocationCoordinate2D, destination: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        self.source = source
        self.destination = destination
    }
    
    // If you are calling the coordinate from a Model, don't forgot to pass it in the function parenthesis.
    func present(in viewController: UIViewController, sourceView: UIView) {
        
        if let source = self.source, let destination = self.destination {
            //            CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.792014, longitude: -114.105279)
            let source = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: source))
            source.name = "Source"
            
            let destination = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: destination))
            destination.name = "Destination"
            
            let okotoks = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 50.725494, longitude: -113.974947)))
            okotoks.name = "okotoks"
            
            MKMapItem.openMaps(
              with: [source, destination],
              launchOptions: [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving]
            )
        }
}
```

Its calling is like:

```
let appleMap = AppleMap(source: source, destination: pickupLocation)
appleMap.present(in: self, sourceView: UIView())
```

Comment: "when it reaches to destination point into my ViewController" What is IT?  If it's the device that runs your app, then how does your app monitor the current GPS position?

Comment: I am calling this function from ViewController, if navigation reaches to the destination point, it should give me some callback, so that I am able to react accordingly.

Comment: You have opened maps to show the route.  Once you do that your app is no longer involved, so no, there is no callback to your app when the destination is reached. If your app has "always" location permission you could set up a geofence region for the destination.

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11, is there any way that I implement Mapkit Navigation into my application, instead opening Mapkit navigation in Map app externally so that I have all the access.

Comment: Only if you add some other turn-by-turn navigation SDK into your app